# Laravel - Get articles from feeds for one user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables:

> articles :
>
> - id
> - feed_id
> - title
>
> feeds :
>
> - id
> - user_id
> - name
>
> users :
>
> - id
> - name

I want get all articles from feeds for one user, I search the Eloquent Relationships...

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define the relation on `User` model. Best option for you situation is to use a [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Article',
        'App\Feed',
        'user_id', // Foreign key on feeds table...
        'feed_id', // Foreign key on articles table...
        'id', // Local key on users table...
        'id' // Local key on feeds table...
    );
}
```

Then make a user object and get his articles:

```
$user = /App/User::with('articles')->find($id);

foreach($user->articles as $article) {
    // do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with this, I have only _id and not all fields...

#attributes: array:1 [▼
        "_id" => ObjectID {#278 ▼
          +"oid": "59c224a09a89203b6e137622"
        }
      ]

Comment: What is this? I mean how did you get it?

Comment: @CélineMartin I have tested it and it works fine. Maybe something is wrong with your models.

Comment: So, I use Laravel MongoDB, my articles is a MongoDB collection, the rest of tables is on MySQL. ID of articles is _id, and rest is id.

Comment: You also can change primary key of Articles on its model by adding protected $primaryKey = '_id';

Answer (score 0):

laravel documentation is always a good start for researching, read about hasManyThrough
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

don't mind if it is in 5.5, there are no significant differences between them

Answer (score 0):

in model

in Articles.php

```
public function Feed()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Feed');
}
```

in Feed.php

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function Articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Articles');
}
```

in User.php

```
public function Feed()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Feed');
}
```

in controller

// To get all articles of user with id = $id

```
$reports2 = Articles::with(array('Feed'=>function($query)use($id){
    $query->with('User');
    $query->where('user_id',$id);
}))->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```